# Preserve insertion order of elements in a data member for Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a `Set<String> set` that I persist with Neo4j Spring in java.  To be able to retrieve elements from that `set` in the order that elements were added to it.  Sets do not retain order.  I have tried using a `Collection<String>/List<String>` instead because `Lists`s have ordering, but Neo4j doesn't like `Collection`.  What else can be used for ordered storage?

EDIT:  By order, I mean insertion order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special implementation of Set, the class `TreeSet` keeps the elements in the set sorted, either by their natural ordering or by asking a `Comparator` how they should be ordered. TreeSets reorders the set whenever you add/remove elements.

There is also the `LinkedHashSet` implementation which keeps the items according to the insertion order.

Collection is an interface that the interfaces Set and List both extend. (And other interfaces as well)

Collection does not guarantee ordering. All they care about is the possibility to add and remove elements. `Set` does not allow more than one copy of each element to be added. The Set interface itself does not guarantee ordering. The `List` interface guarantee ordering but also allows multiple copies of the same element.

Summary: For your case, use LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Thanks, however neo4j won't let me persist anything from `Collection`

Comment: @StephenD `Set` is a subinterface of `Collection`. So all sets are also Collections.

Comment: LinkedHashSet is one I like to use for this sort of thing. TreeSet is for keeping a list sorted by something, LinkedHashSet is for sorting by insertion order.

Comment: @WesFreeman Good thinking! I edited my answer and added that.

Answer (score 0):

List is an ordered collection (also known as a sequence). The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.

```
  List<String> list  new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: In the edit of the question, it states he already tried this.